# Left mouse button not working in Xubuntu session

Tags: xubuntu, mouse

I recent changed from Ubuntu to Xubuntu 12.04. The install worked great for a few days, but suddenly the left mouse button stopped working. The right click and scroll bars work fine.

After a bit of experimenting I discovered that the problem only happens when I set the session to Xubuntu at login. The mouse also works fine in my dual-booted Windows vista.

What could make my mouse stop working like that?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`?

Comment: That file does not exist on my system. Weird.

Comment: Try `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Nope it opens me up for a new file.

Comment: *X now automatically configures itself*, see this   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/, so you will not see `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. To create a new one use `sudo Xorg :1 -configure`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` installed on your system:

```
sudo dpkg -s xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

If yes, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If no, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

Reboot.

Comment: I see no reason why using the beta-quality xorg-edgers PPA would provide a solution to this. I doubt that his mouse driver is outdated.

Comment: Because this is a known issue, and this PPA will hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: If this is a known issue, there should be a launchpad bug number. Since the problem only exists under the Xubuntu session, replacing the entire X stack sounds extreme.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, this means that my method helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Your left mouse button might be remapped or disabled.  Try adjusting the configuration or resetting to defaults in the Xfce control panel, as described here:

http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/mouse

You can check the current mappings using the `xinput` command from the Terminal.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mouseemu virtual mouse                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Look for your mouse in the list and note its id, presented as `id=x`; e.g., 11

The use `xinput` again to get the current button map:

```
$ xinput get-button-map 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If the first number is "0", your mouse button 1 is disabled. Test re-enabling it with:

```
$ xinput set-button-map 11 1
```

Remember to replace "11" with the mouse's id from `xinput list`.

If this gets reset every time you login to your desktop, see if there's a file in your home directory called ".xinputrc" or a directory called .xinput.d/ containing files. Also see if there's an errant ".xinitrc" that might have xinput commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in terminal: `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` this command removes the mouse driver from the kernel, this should solve the problem, but if the mouse still doesn't work try this after the first command: `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps` and this should reinstates it. It is like of turning it off then on

Answer (score -1):

Freantique's solution does not work for my Samsung N210 with Xubuntu 12.04. I find a solution that it works and I posted a step by step tutorial here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12489693#post12489693

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.