# Mouse buttons no longer working after updates

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I did some updates. After restarting the computer, the buttons on my touchpad and wired mouse no longer work.

I had this trouble before with the left button on the touchpad. In that case I plugged a mouse in and it worked fine. Now, I can't do anything except move the mouse around.

I need a fix, fast. I have tried everything I've come across online; some help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It may be solve your problem, I am not sure about this.

Check if you have `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` installed on your system:

```
sudo dpkg -s xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

If yes, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If no, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

Reboot.

Source : [Left mouse button not working in Xubuntu session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184222/left-mouse-button-not-working-in-xubuntu-session)